# Extracting points with distance tolerance along line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, line, proximity, point-creation

How I can delete points along a line, with a distance tolerance?

As you can see in the figure, the points near the line should stay, the points between the lines should be deleted.

[image: example]

Comment: Buffer the line layer by `x` m, then use `select by postion` and return every point, which intersects or is within the buffer.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

There is a possibility using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume we have the following layers *'points_along'* and *'lines'*, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible *to extract only those points that are within a distance tolerance, in the case below 100m were used*.

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM "points_along" AS p, "line" AS l
WHERE ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine(p.geometry, l.geometry)) < 100
```

The output Virtual Layer with its Attribute table will look as following

[image: output]

Answer (score 4):

1. The easiest method would be to build a buffer first with [`Vector -> Geoprocessing tools -> Buffer`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#buffer)
2. Then delete all the points within that buffer with [`Vector -> Geoprocessing tools -> Difference`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#difference).

Answer (score 4):

A solution based on QGIS expressions: Use select by expression with this expression (changing the distance in line 5), then delete the selected points:

```
disjoint (
    $geometry,
    buffer (
        overlay_nearest ('line',$geometry)[0],
        40000  -- change distance here
    )
)
```

*Red buffers for visualization purpose only: yellow points are selected by the expression from above:*
[image]